# Add empty rows each certain rows in a multiindex data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
probe_names  PLAGL1  GRB10  MEST   H19  KCNQ1OT1  MEG3  MEG8  SNRPN  PEG3  \
Jemima   0     0.55   0.53  0.53  0.47      0.62  0.11  0.83   0.50  0.49   
        1     0.51   0.46  0.53  0.52      0.47  0.00  0.91   0.47  0.54   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.55       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.50   
        0     0.54   0.59  0.53  0.47      0.66  0.13  0.90   0.51  0.53   
        1     0.48   0.45  0.54  0.50      0.47  0.00  0.90   0.50  0.53   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.54       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.53   
Elena    0     0.54   0.55  0.55  0.57      0.53  0.58  0.55   0.52  0.45   
        1     0.53   0.49  0.53  0.65      0.38  0.62  0.48   0.49  0.55   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.66       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.42   
        0     0.51   0.53  0.55  0.62      0.52  0.57  0.53   0.50  0.48   
        1     0.48   0.45  0.52  0.63      0.38  0.59  0.46   0.53  0.55   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.63       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.45
```

And I want to add 2 empty/NaN rows each 3 rows

```
probe_names  PLAGL1  GRB10  MEST   H19  KCNQ1OT1  MEG3  MEG8  SNRPN  PEG3  \
Jemima   0     0.55   0.53  0.53  0.47      0.62  0.11  0.83   0.50  0.49   
        1     0.51   0.46  0.53  0.52      0.47  0.00  0.91   0.47  0.54   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.55       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.50  
        3
        4
        0     0.54   0.59  0.53  0.47      0.66  0.13  0.90   0.51  0.53   
        1     0.48   0.45  0.54  0.50      0.47  0.00  0.90   0.50  0.53   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.54       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.53   
        3
        4
Elena    0     0.54   0.55  0.55  0.57      0.53  0.58  0.55   0.52  0.45   
        1     0.53   0.49  0.53  0.65      0.38  0.62  0.48   0.49  0.55   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.66       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.42   
        0     0.51   0.53  0.55  0.62      0.52  0.57  0.53   0.50  0.48   
        1     0.48   0.45  0.52  0.63      0.38  0.59  0.46   0.53  0.55   
        2      NaN    NaN   NaN  0.63       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.45
        3
        4
```

I don't know how to do this in multi-index tables. I have checked on the internet but I can't see something really similar.

Comment: Can you provide the constructor for your dataframe with `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PWwSRHSoZziwsRSVlqHBKHGSHTnDgCGwThNAVT3GfyY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include that dictionary in your post. Don't link to external sites.

Comment: I can't. It says too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reindex` to a MultiIndex:

```
#include an extra index level to differentiate between duplicated indices
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0,1],sort=False).cumcount(),append=True)

#create a 3-level multiindex
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0],range(df.index.levels[1].max()+3),df.index.levels[2]])

#reindex, sort, and drop the extra level
output = df.reindex(midx).sort_index(level=[0,2],ascending=[False,True]).droplevel(2)

>>> output
          PLAGL1  GRB10  MEST   H19  KCNQ1OT1  MEG3  MEG8  SNRPN  PEG3
Jemima 0    0.55   0.53  0.53  0.47      0.62  0.11  0.83   0.50  0.49
       1    0.51   0.46  0.53  0.52      0.47  0.00  0.91   0.47  0.54
       2     NaN    NaN   NaN  0.55       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.50
       3     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
       4     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
       0    0.54   0.59  0.53  0.47      0.66  0.13  0.90   0.51  0.53
       1    0.48   0.45  0.54  0.50      0.47  0.00  0.90   0.50  0.53
       2     NaN    NaN   NaN  0.54       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.53
       3     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
       4     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
Elena  0    0.54   0.55  0.55  0.57      0.53  0.58  0.55   0.52  0.45
       1    0.53   0.49  0.53  0.65      0.38  0.62  0.48   0.49  0.55
       2     NaN    NaN   NaN  0.66       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.42
       3     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
       4     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
       0    0.51   0.53  0.55  0.62      0.52  0.57  0.53   0.50  0.48
       1    0.48   0.45  0.52  0.63      0.38  0.59  0.46   0.53  0.55
       2     NaN    NaN   NaN  0.63       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN  0.45
       3     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
       4     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! in the second line of your code

Comment: can it be a pandas version issue?

Comment: Are you using different data than in your sample? If yes, provide a sample which generates the error you mention. For reference, I'm on pandas 1.4.2 but I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: No. I am using the same data I generate the dict. How do you convert the dict into the pandas data frame

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(dictionary)`?

Comment: I have converted the data frame into a dict (with the code you passed me) and then from the dictionary to a new pandas data frame. With this new (and in theory equal data frame) I have run the code you suggest in the answer and it worked. So somehow, the original data frame and the one created from the dict are not the same

Comment: Apart from that, if you read your solution, half of the data is missing. For example Jemima at column PLAGL1, there are 4 values in the input (0.55,0.51,0.54,0.48).   However, in your output, I only can read the last two values.

Comment: I have put a picture in the word document with the output and it is identical that the one you show. If you see my desired output, it should be 10 rows per person.

Comment: Interesting, you are right. if I do my_dict = data_no_control_patient.to_dict(), half of the data is gone. However, I am sure that data_no_control_patient in complet. What is going on?

Comment: It's because your indices are duplicated and a dictionary can't have duplicate indices. Did you try the edited answer?